# Make Looping Table PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to make looping table in my project.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">  
<?php  
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)  
{  
echo "<tr>";  
for ($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)  
  {  
  echo "<td>$i"</td>";  
  }  
  echo "</tr>";  
  }  
?>  
</table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

I want to make looping table with auto number in the first column. But I get response like this:
[image]

Can some one tell me how I can make it only in the first column?

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample output how you want?

Comment: First thing I notice `echo "<td>$i"</td>";`  you need to fix that.

Comment: already add result what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just move your `$i` outside of inner loop and add empty table data. Reduce your inner loop iteration by 1 count:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">  
<?php  
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)  
{  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>$i</td>";  
for ($j=2;$j<=5;$j++)  
  {  
  echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";  
  }  
  echo "</tr>";  
  }  
?>  
</table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

---

**Note:** Typo in your question - `echo "<td>$i"</td>";`  to `echo "<td>$i</td>";`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer if you want this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">  
<?php  
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)  
{  
  echo "<tr>";  
  echo "<td>".$i."</td>";  
  echo "</tr>";  
}  
?>  
</table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code from
 `echo "<td>$i"</td>";`
 to
 `echo "<td>".$i."</td>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">  
<?php  
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++) {  
   echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>".$i."</td>"; 
    echo "<td></td>"; 
    echo "<td></td>"; 
    echo "<td></td>"; 
    echo "<td></td>"; 
    echo "<td></td>"; 
   echo "</tr>"; 
}    
?>  
</table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Slightly different approach than Thamilan. Both work though. This way iterates 6 rows and places each iteration of `$i` in the first td each time, while leaving the others blank for whatever use you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">  
<?php  
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)  
{  
echo "<tr>";  
for ($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)  
  {  
  if($j==1)echo "<td>$i</td>";
  else 
      echo "<td> </td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
</table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
One more tip.

<pre>
<table style="border:2px solid black;">  
<?php  
$Array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$Table='';
foreach($Array AS $Data){
   $Table.="<tr><td>".$Data."</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>"; 
    $Table.= "</tr>"; 
}   
echo $Table; 
?>  
</table>  
</pre>
```